# publish nodejs express on iis 7

Tags: windows, node.js, iis-7, express, publish

I'm using:
node 0.6.19
npm 1.1.24
on Win7 pro and iis 7.

I have a folder named 'test' in iisnode/www/. In this folder I want to create a fresh nodejs-express-app.

what I did

- create a folder in another Directory like D:/development/node/test
- run in console: npm install express -g
- run: express -t jade
- run: npm install -d

with 'localhost:3000' all is fine.

- Now I replace the port '3000' with 'process.env.port' in app.js
- Copy all files in iisnode/www/test
- get the web.config and set the handlers and rewrite rules

  ```
  <handlers>
    <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
  </handlers>

  <rewrite>
      <rules>
          <rule name="express">
              <match url="test/*" />
              <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js" />
          </rule>
      </rules>
  </rewrite>
  ```

I restartet the iis and get: "Cannot GET /node/test/app"

Where is my mistake?
Can someone help me?

I'm not a master with the IIS.